# Equalizing the space between the quads of a polyloop

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

Is there any way to equalize the area shown with red lines for the whole loop? I tried with the looptools addon but I couldn't do it.

[image]

Comment: tbh i have no idea what you mean? horizontal? vertical? often it is a good idea to make a small sketch how it should look.

Comment: Horizontal as shown with the red lines.

Comment: You can select the border edge extrude it outwards select the new face loop and use inset (i) in outset mode(o during operation), then delete unneeded geometry like for example dissolve the edge loops you no longer need and tidy the messy bits.

Comment: Thanks that worked!